# Is there a way to calculate standard errors when using predict.mppm?

Tags: spatstat

I'm using `spatstat` to run some `mppm` models and would like to be able to calculate standard errors for the predictions as in `predict.ppm`. I could use `predict.ppm` on each point process individually of course, but I'm wondering if this in invalid for any reason or if there is a better way of doing so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not yet implemented as an option in `predict.mppm`. (It is on our long list of things to do. I will move it closer to the top of the list.)

However, it is available by applying `predict.ppm` to each element of `subfits(model)`, where `model` was the original fitted model of class `mppm`. Something like:

```
m <- mppm(......)
fits <- subfits(m)
Y <- lapply(fits, predict, se=TRUE)
```

Just to clarify, `fits[[i]]` is a point process model, of class `ppm`, for the data in row `i` of the data hyperframe, **implied** by the big model `m`. The parameter estimates and variance estimates in `fits[[i]]` are based on information from the entire hyperframe. This is not the same as fitting a separate model of class `ppm` to the data in each row of the hyperframe and calculating predictions and standard errors for those fits.